# Subscribe in MATLAB to a ROS node on another PC

Tags: ros, matlab, ros-melodic, talker, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have MATLAB running on a Windows-PC and ROS running on a separate Linux-PC. Both are connected in a network. On the Linux-PC I started ROS with the command "roscore". On the MATLAB-PC I used the commands 

master = robotics.ros.Core
and 

node = robotics.ros.Node('/test')
to create a node with the name /test (after specifying the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP on ROS and MATLAB). I want to declare this node to a subscriber for the /chatter-topic. Messages are published by a talker (Standard node, described in the ROS tutorial). The problem is, that I can't receive messages on the node /test. To specify the publisher, MATLAB advertises the command 
 
sub = robotics.ros.Subscriber(node,'/chatter','std_msgs/String')"
 
 To use this, I have to insert the node name of the talker, which is not know. 
My question is, if there is a possibility to receive messages to this topic. If I start a listener in ROS and a publisher in MATLAB, then the message transfer is possible.


Regards,
Rick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295386/subscribe-in-matlab-to-a-ros-node-on-another-pc/) by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q230737. This is most likely very closely related, if not a duplicate of that question.

> ```
> sub = robotics.ros.Subscriber(node,'/chatter','std_msgs/String')"
> ```

> To use this, I have to insert the node name of the talker, which is not know.

this is just one of the possible ways to initialise a `Subscriber` object. The [documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/robotics.subscriber.html) has a few more that don't require you to know the name of the publisher.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on 2018-06-26**:
Thank you for your answer. I also tried rossubscriber without a node, but in the rqt_graph I saw, that the MATLAB node is also the publisher. That's why I tried this way.

**Comment by [Rick](https://answers.ros.org/users/36114/rick/) on 2018-06-27**:
Now it works. Thanks a lot!